# Why can't I make my input text any wider?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Been struggling with what I think should be simple but I am not getting anywhere.

I have the following html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <fieldset class="fieldset-class">
            <legend class="legend-class">Filter Risks</legend>
            <div class="form-group" style="border: solid 2px red;">
                <label for="insuredFilter" class="control-label col-xs-2">Insured</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10" style="border: solid 2px blue;">
                    <input id="insuredFilter" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="vm.insured" typeahead="insured as insured.InsuredName for insured in vm.getFilteredInsureds($viewValue)" typeahead-editable="false" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="yearOfAccountFilter" class="control-label col-xs-2">Year of Account</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <select id="yearOfAccountFilter" class="form-control widthauto-class" ng-model="vm.yearOfAccount" ng-options="option.YearOfAccountText for option in vm.yearsOfAccount track by option.YearOfAccountID"></select>
                </div>
                <label for="riskReferenceFilter" class="control-label col-xs-2">Risk Reference</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input id="riskReferenceFilter" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.riskFilteredByRiskReference" typeahead="risk as risk.RiskReference for risk in vm.getFilteredRisksByRiskReference($viewValue)" typeahead-editable="false" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn pull-right fieldset-button-class" ng-click="vm.clearFilter()">Clear</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-default pull-right fieldset-button-class" ng-click="vm.filterRisks()">Filter</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Using Bootstrap 3, this looks like:

[image: Input screen]

NB: I've added the red and blue borders so it is easy to see that the input box does not come close to filling the container div.

No matter what I try, I am unable to make the Insured input any wider.

I have used the grid system and given the container div 10 columns, which I imagine is plenty.

I thought it might be an issue to do with the angular typeahead directive, but having taken that out, the width issue remains.

I would appreciate any help the community can offer. I admit to being a CSS neophyte so if I've done something stupid please point it out to me.

Many thanks,

Ash

p.s. I should point out I am stuck with Internet Explorer 11 (corporate standard) and I cannot use Compatability View with my angular code.

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, try the F12 tools in your browser of choice, look at the computed css and it'll tell you where the width is coming from

Comment: Nothing wrong with ur code.. I tried ur code, I am getting width 100% properly

Comment: Added your code in a fiddle. Works perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17209/

Comment: That's interesting. Any ideas why I can't get it to work? Internet Explorer?